# How can I reliably open a server/client connection with RSelenium under Linux?

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

**Update:** As of RSelenium 1.7.9 the described problems have disappeared.

I know, similar questions have been asked, but their solutions didn't work for me.

**Summary:**
I would like to open a Selenium-server and a client under Linux via R's package RSelenium.
But even though I try two ways described in the documentation (while I want to avoid docker)
it doesn't work reliably.

**My system:**
Linux 5.19, R 4.2.1,
RSelenium 1.7.7, selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-2,
chromedriver 104.0.5112.79-2.1, geckodriver 0.31.0 (binman),
I have tested with OpenJDK 11 and OpenJDK 18 (currently)

**I. Selenium via JAVA**

In the Linux-console

```
@localhost:~/Documents/selenium> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-4.0.0-alpha-2.jar
20:04:49.470 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 4.0.0-alpha-2, revision: f148142cf8
20:04:49.526 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
20:04:49.730 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
20:04:49.793 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

In R I type:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444L, browserName = "chrome", version = "104.0.5112.79")
```

and get in the Linux console the output:

```
20:07:49.463 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "javascriptEnabled": true,
  "nativeEvents": true,
  "version": "104.0.5112.79"
}
20:07:49.465 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 104.0.5112.79 (3cf3e8c8a07d104b9e1260c910efb8f383285dc5-refs/branch-heads/5112@{#1307}) on port 15987
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
20:07:50.023 INFO [ProtocolHandshake.createSession] - Detected dialect: W3C
20:07:50.044 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session 732d7c7ddfeaed42fc80fac54f91fcb5 (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

The Chrome-Browser opens and the R console gives me the kiss of death:

```
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed initialization
```

That means, I cannot use the R-console for navigation. The other approach:

**II. Selenium via RSelenium::rsDriver**

```
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="firefox", port = 4567L, verbose = FALSE)
```

*mostly* yields (with a browser window opening)

```
Could not open firefox browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed initialization
Check server log for further details.
```

*BUT*: The very same code *can* work! Randomly. Or after a long time having R open?!? Endless testing?!?
Suddenly I get several running server/client connections including navigation on web-pages:

```
$acceptInsecureCerts
[1] FALSE

$browserName
[1] "firefox"

$browserVersion
[1] "103.0.2"

$`moz:accessibilityChecks`
[1] FALSE

$`moz:buildID`
[1] "20220815180539"

$`moz:geckodriverVersion`
[1] "0.31.0"
etc.pp.
```

But at the latest when I reboot my PC, I get the same error-message again. It also can work after deleting and reinstalling the four drivers via RSelenium in ./local/share. Or when I try the same again, it simply doesn't.
I have never run in such a kind of problem with randomness. Where can it come from?

PS: The server log, if it doesn't work, *can* have additional lines, which I add:

```
> rD$server$log()
$stderr                                                                                            
[26] "Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.jsm"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[27] "Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.sys.mjs"                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[28] "console.error: \"Error during quit-application-granted: [Exception... \\\"File error: Not found\\\"  nsresult: \\\"0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)\\\"  location: \\\"JS frame :: resource:///modules/BrowserGlue.jsm :: _onQuitApplicationGranted/tasks< :: line 2006\\\"  data: no]\""
[29] "1661020441351\tMarionette\tINFO\tStopped listening on port 42425"                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[30] "JavaScript error: chrome://remote/content/marionette/cert.js, line 57: NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsICertOverrideService.setDisableAllSecurityChecksAndLetAttackersInterceptMyData]"                                      

$stdout
character(0)
```

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/73429435/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Have you tried using the `wdman` package? It takes the pain of Selenium servers away.

Comment: @dcuska. This leads to the same error in R. If i open the server with wdman::selenium and type "http://localhost:4573/" in my browser, I get a warm welcome "Happy Testing!" though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following approach which relies on Docker :

```
library(RSelenium)
url <- "https://www.hubs.com/3d-printing/#/?place=New%20York&latitude=40.7144&longitude=-74.006&distanceLimit=250&distanceUnit=miles&shipsToCountry=US&shipsToState=NY"
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
```